# Is there any advantage to int i = array.length over just calling array.length twice?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, compiler-construction

Is any benefit--small as it may be--of putting the length of an array into an int in this situation, or is simply calling array.length twice better? Or does compiler optimization make these approaches equivalent?

No int:

```
Vector<String> vs = new Vector<String>(a_o.length);
for(int i = 0; i < a_o.length; i++)  {
   vs.add(a_o[i]);
}
```

int:

```
int iLen = a_o.length;
Vector<String> vs = new Vector<String>(iLen);
for(int i = 0; i < iLen; i++)  {
   vs.add(a_o[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is smart, trust it. It'll optimize it.

Don't waste time on performance issues like this one, worry more about other things like data structures..

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, a decent compiler the compiler will do this optimization for you.
And even if not, the hit is minimal. You are probably going to suffer much more from using `Vector`. see [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: Point taken about Vector. I'm considering changing it to ArrayList as mentioned there. Thank you.